# Implementing partition_unique and stable_partition_unique algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl-algorithm

I'm looking for a way to partition a set of ordered elements such that all unique elements occur before their respective duplicates, noting that [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) is not applicable as duplicate elements are overwritten, I thought of using [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition). Calling this algorithm `partition_unique`, I also need the corresponding `stable_partition_unique` (i.e. like [`stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition)).

A basic implementation of `partition_unique` is:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>

template <typename BidirIt, typename BinaryPredicate = std::equal_to<void>>
BidirIt partition_unique(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, BinaryPredicate p = BinaryPredicate {})
{
    using ValueTp = typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::value_type;

    std::unordered_set<ValueTp, std::hash<ValueTp>, BinaryPredicate> seen {};
    seen.reserve(std::distance(first, last));

    return std::partition(first, last,
                          [&p, &seen] (const ValueTp& value) {
                              return seen.insert(value).second;
                          });
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vals {1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 10};

    const auto it = partition_unique(std::begin(vals), std::end(vals));

    std::cout << "Unique values: ";
    std::copy(std::begin(vals), it, std::ostream_iterator<int> {std::cout, " "}); // Unique values: 1 10 2 4 5 9 7 
    std::cout << '\n' << "Duplicate values: ";
    std::copy(it, std::end(vals), std::ostream_iterator<int> {std::cout, " "}); // Duplicate values: 7 5 5 1
}
```

The corresponding `stable_partition_unqiue` can be achieved by replacing `std::partition` with  `std::stable_partition`.

The problem with these approaches is that they unnecessarily buffer all unique values in the `std::unordered_set` (which also adds a hash function requirement), which shouldn't be required as the elements are sorted. It's not too much work to come up with a better implementation for `partition_unique`, but an implementation of `stable_partition_unique` seems considerably more difficult, and I'd rather not [implement this myself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) if possible.

Is there a way to use existing algorithms to achieve optimal `partition_unique` and `stable_ partition_unique` algorithms?

Comment: Although it will probably work with most implementations of `std::partition()`, I would assume that the predicate is *not* allowed to return different values for the same argument at different times.  The fact that your predicate does means that it could cause e.g. a parallel implementation of `std::partition()` to crash.

Comment: @j_random_hacker `std::partition` is only allowed to examine each value once due to complexity requirements, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That's an interesting observation.  AFAICT this would actually allow for a correct parallel implementation of `std::partition()` even in the face of "non-constant" predicates (with the onus being on the caller to provide any necessary mutual exclusion).

Comment: Why not use stable_sort()? Any duplicates will be immediately after the first element and order is preserved. Best of all the algorithm doesn't rely on additional containers. stable_partition() also preserves order but duplicates wont necessarily be adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

Create a queue to hold the duplicates. Then, initialize two indexes, `src` and `dest`, starting at index 1, and go through the list. If the current item (`list[src]`) is equal to the previous item (`list[dest-1]`), then copy it to the queue. Otherwise, copy it to `list[dest]` and increment `dest`.

When you've exhausted the list, copy items from the queue to the tail of the original list.

Something like:

```
Queue dupQueue
int src = 1
int dest = 1
while (src < list.count)
{
    if (list[src] == list[dest-1])
    {
        // it's a duplicate.
        dupQueue.push(list[src])
    }
    else
    {
        list[dest] = list[src]
        ++dest
    }
    ++src
}
while (!dupQueue.IsEmpty)
{
    list[dest] = dupQueue.pop()
    ++dest
}
```

I know the STL has a queue. Whether it has an algorithm similar to the above, I don't know.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to implement the algorithm. He wants to combine existing algorithms. The standard `stable_partition` is implemented in almost the same way you described, in GCC's STL. So it would be a reimplementation to use your answer. Unfortunately, the more I think about this question, the more I think you *must* reimplement ...

Comment: @fjardon: I realize that the OP would rather not implement it himself. As you say, though, it looks like he'll have to. And, contrary to his assertion in the question, it's not "considerably more difficult" than `stable_partition`: just replace the unordered set with a queue, and there you have it.

Comment: @JimMischel It's not difficult to implement a naive implementation, but a good `std::stable_parition` (and hence `stable_partition_unique`) is considerably more complex - it must implement a slower fallback depending on available memory, and can be optimised for different iterator types. Take a look at the [implementation in libc++](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/algorithm), and I think you'll agree.